# Is it possible to disable the for update clause for SELECT statement in PL SQL developer

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

What I want to do is don't allow the user to update records using the for update clause in PL SQL developer. The user has to write and update, insert or delete query to update records. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `for update` clause can only be disabled for a read-only transaction.

Run this query to set your transaction to read-only.

```
SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
```

But in that case, you cannot run any other DML statements too. That is if you want to explicitly write an `update` query, you cannot do that unless you run a `commit` query which basically ends the read-only transaction, which also subsequently enables `select` queries with the `for update` clause.

So no, you cannot disable it without disabling all DML queries.